# Python: Checking if you can connect to a given url (urllib2)

Tags: python, urllib2

Is there a way beyond catching exceptions(HTTPError,URLError), to check if access to a url is permitted.

I have to constantly(every 30 secs) ping a url (using urllib2.open)(which might or might not be valid).
And throwing and catching exceptions each time seems excessive. I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: would using requests.get() and checking  r.status_code == requests.codes.ok work?

Comment: Check for `200` when receiving the status code from the HTTP request as @PadraicCunningham suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using try/except.  That's the way to do such things in python.

> it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
>>> r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
True
>>> r.status_code
200
```

[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)

Comment: I tried this, but I still got an exception. So had to just catch the exception. thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: No worries, I actually tried something similar and had to use a try/except. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443651/python-network-calls-before-network-service-is-up/23443897#23443897