# Python: Network calls before network service is up

Tags: python

I have a script that gets launched on boot, and it is possible that it would be launched before networking is fully up.

The following code fails if it is run before networking is up, if it gets called again later it succeeds.

Even if I increase the tries to 5 minutes, it will still continue until the 5 minutes and then return false, even though networking comes up probably less than 30 seconds after the script launches.

Rather than just sleeping for 1 minute before making any attempt, is there a way to make the following code work and not die if the ethernet is not up ?

```
self.TRIES = 60
self.URL="http://www.somedomain.com"

## Do we have internet
def isup():
  try:
    urllib2.urlopen(self.URL).close()
    return True
  except urllib2.URLError,e:
    pass
  return False

## Try the lookup
while (self.TRIES > 0):
  if isup():
    check()
    break
  self.TRIES = self.TRIES-1
  time.sleep(1)
```

## Edit

During OS bootup (Arch Linux) the adapter (eth0 in this case) and the networking service are initially not running, and are started during the bootup process.

It appears that urllib2 (and other network-related calls) die if it is called before networking service is fully up, and subsequent calls will always result in a fail.

This is NOT the same as just disconnecting the ethernet cable, if you just unplug the ethernet cable and call the function (class) then it will succeed, but if it is called BEFORE the networking service is fully up, it will fail and die.

I can solve this problem by adding a time.sleep(30) to the top of the code, this then gives enough time for the O/S network service to fully start and the script works 100% as expected.

Comment: could you not just check the status code ?

Comment: What do you mean by before networking is up? What OS are you working on?

Comment: I am also wondering what you mean by "before networking is up."  I just tested on my machine by disconnecting from the web, running a failed line of `urllib2.urlopen('http://www.yahoo.com').close()` and then reconnecting and trying again.  It works perfectly.  Have you tested to make sure it ever actually pulls data properly?  Just because you have network connectivity doesn't mean you have a working DNS, valid outbound ports, ... etc.

Comment: As Namey as mentioned, I have tested this code snippet too and it worked fine in my case.

Comment: A completely other approach could be to set up your init scripts so that this one here is definitely called after setting up networking.

Comment: During system bootup (Arch Linux) the network adapter is initially down and is brought up. If I attempt any network related activities when the adapter is not UP, then it will die. This is not the same as just disconnecting the ethernet cable when the adapter is already up.

Answer (score 2):

use requests and check the status code?

```
import requests
In [36]: r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')

In [37]: r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
Out[37]: True

In [38]: r.status_code
Out[38]: 200

200
In [33]:  r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/bad')

In [34]: r.status_code
Out[34]: 404

In [35]: r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
Out[35]: False

def isup():
    try:
        r = requests.get(self.URL)
        return r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as:

```
def isup():
  try:
    urllib2.urlopen(self.URL).close()
    return True
  except urllib2.URLError,e:
    pass
  return False

## Try the lookup
while not isup():
    pass           #or replace pass with time.sleep(1) or time.sleep(0.5)
check()
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that, it will continue forever, it is not that my wait time is too short, but that urllib2 appears to die if it is called when the network is not up !

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use `ping`?

```
def isUp():
    ret = os.system("ping -c 1 www.google.com")
    return (ret != 0)
```

NOTE: this does not work on Windows as is but you got the idea...